# Database reader closes before reading the data

Tags: c#, ado.net, mysql-connector, mysql.data

I want to query my MySQL database by using the MySQL.Data connector. *I know that I could use the Entity Framework or other handy tools similiar to ORMs e.g. Dapper. But I would like to try out the "native" way.* First of all I created a base repository dealing with the the query execution

```
public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    private async Task<MySqlConnection> GetDatabaseConnection()
    {
        string databaseConnectionString = "connection string";
        MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(databaseConnectionString);

        await mySqlConnection.OpenAsync();

        return mySqlConnection;
    }
    
    private async Task<DbDataReader> Execute(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameterValues)
    {
        await using MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = await GetDatabaseConnection();
        
        MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand()
        {
            CommandText = commandText,
            Connection = mySqlConnection
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameterValue in parameterValues)
        {
            mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterValue.Key, parameterValue.Value);
        }
        
        await mySqlCommand.PrepareAsync();
        
        return await mySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    }
    
    protected async Task<TResult> Read<TResult>(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameterValues, Func<DbDataReader, Task<TResult>> action)
    {
        DbDataReader dbDataReader = await Execute(commandText, parameterValues);
        
        return await action(dbDataReader);
    }
    
    protected async Task<int> Write(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameterValues)
    {
        DbDataReader dbDataReader = await Execute(commandText, parameterValues);

        return dbDataReader.RecordsAffected;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a `Read` and `Modify` method. Since MySQL is not able to return the inserted/updated row (as Postgres does) I only return the amount of affected rows for update and delete. *I know the base repository does not support transactions yet, but ignore it for now.* The following example demonstrates the usage

```
    public Task<User> GetUserAsync(string username)
    {
        return Read<User>(
            "SELECT * FROM person WHERE username = @username", 
            new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "username", username }
            },
            async dbDataReader =>
            {
                try
                {
                    bool recordFound = await dbDataReader.ReadAsync();
                    
                    if (!recordFound)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }
                    
                    // ...
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            });
    }
```

The problem is that when the debugger hits `await dbDataReader.ReadAsync()` I get this exception

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Invalid attempt to
> Read when reader is closed.

Why does the reader close too early? How can I fix that?

---

**Update**

As already mentioned in the comments the reason is that `await using MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = await GetDatabaseConnection();` closes the connection at the end of the calling method.

I could handle the whole reader logic in each repository method but I want to avoid repeating myself in each repository method.

Is there a way I can redesign the `BaseRepository` methods so that they won't close the connection too early?

Comment: The reason is that this line: `return await mySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();` will return an open reader, but then this first line in the method: `await using MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = await GetDatabaseConnection();` will close the connection as soon as the method returns. Simply put, you will have to redesign your code so that either it consumes the reader in your method, before returning, or you will have to avoid using the `using` keyword in the first line and find a different way to close the connection once you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I found a solution that works for me. I have to work with callbacks and make `Execute` call a callback before closing the reader instead. So the updated code would be

```
private async Task<TResult> Execute<TResult>(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameterValues, Func<DbDataReader, Task<TResult>> action)
{
    await using MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = await GetDatabaseConnection();
        
    MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand()
    {
        CommandText = commandText,
        Connection = mySqlConnection
    };
    
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameterValue in parameterValues)
    {
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterValue.Key, parameterValue.Value);
    }
        
    await mySqlCommand.PrepareAsync();
        
    DbDataReader dbDataReader = await mySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    return await action(dbDataReader);
}
    
protected async Task<TResult> Read<TResult>(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameterValues, Func<DbDataReader, Task<TResult>> action)
{
    return await Execute(commandText, parameterValues, action);
}
    
protected async Task<int> Write(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameterValues)
{
    return await Execute(commandText, parameterValues, dbDataReader => Task.FromResult(dbDataReader.RecordsAffected));
}
```

What do you think about it? Improvements are highly appreciated :)